# ExtJS 5 Create Application Without Using a Viewport

Tags: extjs5

I had started writing an application to be embedded inside an existing webpage:

[image]

I initially created the app with sencha CMD, but learned that the viewport took up the whole webpage when I included the script in the HTML.  I then followed this guide: http://extjs.eu/single-file-extjs-5-application/ to create a working example inside the webpage.  I now realize its a bad idea to try to create a manageable application with this, and I am now trying to port it over.

My attempt creates a webpage with only the word header:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>
<body><h1>Header</h1><div id="myDiv"></div></body>
</html>
```

application.js:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'MyApp',

    controllers: [
        'MainController'
    ],

    views: ['MyApp.view.MainView'],
    stores: [
        // TODO: add global / shared stores here
    ],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            layout: 'fit',
            renderTo: 'myDiv',
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    title: 'example',
                    html: 'textfield'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',

    extend: 'MyApp.Application'
});
```

MainView.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.panel',
    alias: 'widget.mainview',
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            cfg = {}
            ;

        Ext.apply(cfg, {
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    align: 'stretch'
                },
                items: [{
                    title: 'title',
                    xtype: 'barcode'}]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Sorry for the long post. I have no clue what I'm doing. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you don't need to create application in that case. You can use ExtJS components without application, and in that case it seems resonable. Use `renderTo` to set rendering target.

Example:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'myDiv', // id of target html element
        html: 'something'
    });
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/f6qku062/2/